# Display the name of the billing and shipping country instead of the country code for the current user only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

inspired by: [Get state name instead of the code in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808282/get-state-name-instead-of-the-code-in-woocommerce) [Display a preview of the custom field data in the Edit Billing and Shipping Address section on the my account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380189/display-a-preview-of-the-custom-field-data-in-the-edit-billing-and-shipping-addr?noredirect=1#comment112073789_63380189) And in the answers of the friend @LoicTheAztec I intend to show the name of the country in the section **(Edit Billing and Shipping Address)** **of the page my account** with the following code, but it only shows me the country code instead of the full country name:`

```
<?php
$custom_user_meta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'billing_country', true);

if( ! empty($custom_user_meta) )
    { ?>
<p> <?php
printf( '<strong>Country / Region:</strong> ' . esc_html( '%s' ), esc_html($custom_user_meta)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
}
?>
```

`
I also require it in the same way to show the name of the shipping country.

I appreciate a lot in what you could guide me please.

Comment: I believe this answer your question [Getting country name from country code in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528454/getting-country-name-from-country-code-in-woocommerce). So you get `echo WC()->countries->countries[ $custom_user_meta ];`

Comment: Hello @7uc1f3r not because that post refers to obtaining the country of the order. I need to get the name of the billing and shipping country for the current user.

Comment: well, instead of using `$order->get_shipping_country()`, you could use `WC()->countries->countries[ $custom_user_meta ];`.

Comment: @7uc1f3r that shows nothing. you can add the complete code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `WC()->countries->countries[ 'COUNTRY CODE' ];`

```php
<?php
$custom_user_meta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'billing_country', true);

if( ! empty($custom_user_meta) ) {
?>
    <p>
    <?php
    // Get country name
    $country_name = WC()->countries->countries[ $custom_user_meta ];
    
    printf( '<strong>Country / Region:</strong> ' . esc_html( '%s' ), esc_html($country_name) );
    ?> 
    </p>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: It worked very well, thank you very much.